# Como aumentar badge en IOS cuando la aplicación está en segundo plano?

Tags: angular, ios, ionic3, fcm

Estoy desarrollando una app con Ionic y recibe notificaciones desde FCM y para aumentar el contador del badge de la app utilice la funcionalidad nativa de Ionic: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/badge/

Mi problema es que el contador solo cambia cuando la app esta en uso pero cuando minimizo la app y recibo una notificacion el contador del badge no se incrementa.

Como podría incrementar el badge cuando la app esta en segundo plano?

Gracias de antemano :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu respuesta esta acá:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14256643/update-badge-with-push-notification-while-app-in-background

Basicamente tienes que agregar un parámetro en la información que se envía en la push Notification, el parámetro "badge".

"badge" : 1 (Número que quieres que aparezca)

Acá te dejo la documentación oficial que lo explica https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/PayloadKeyReference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH17-SW1